# EclipseRCP - Update menu items programmcatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Ik have used [this](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/12/03/commands-menu-runtime/) tutorial to define a menu that is built up during runtime. But the next step I want to take is when some event occurs I want to re-build this menu programmatically, for instance by saying to the menu manager, refresh or something like that? Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the menu manager to remove all items each time the menu is shown, giving you the opportunity to rebuild your menu:

```
MenuManager mm = new MenuManager();
mm.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

mm.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
        if(giraffes) {
            Action giraffeAction = new Action("Giraffe") {
                public void run() {
                    // do giraffe-y stuff
                }
            };
            mgr.add(giraffeAction);
        }
    }
});

Control myControl = myViewer.getControl();
myControl().setMenu(mm.createContextMenu(myControl));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that only a subset of the menu under "File" is dynamic and should be re-built, the rest is static and should stay untouched. Is it possible to remove only a specific menu contribution en rebuild that instead of removing all the items?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `ExtensionContributionFactory`, use `org.eclipse.ui.menus` to add a `dynamic` element to the menu you want.  The implementation class you provide subclasses `org.eclipse.ui.actions.CompoundContributionItem` and you will have the opportunity to rebuild that part of the menu on every menu open.

EDIT: add pointer to example.

See http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions/plugin.xml#n666 for the plugin.xml difference.  The implementing class is also contained in that plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please give (or point me to) an example of the solution you propose?